# Create Backup policy in BackRestore api in Azure Service Fabric is throwing error "FABRIC_E_BACKUP_POLICY_DOES_NOT_EXIST"

Tags: backup, azure-service-fabric, restore

I am getting error 
{"Error":{"Code":"FABRIC_E_BACKUP_POLICY_DOES_NOT_EXIST","Message":"Fabric Backup Policy doesn't exist"}}

when calling create backup policy using backuprestore api

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicefabric/sfclient-v62-api-createbackuppolicy

expected result is to create a backup policy, but actually i am getting backup policy does not exist.

Comment: Make sure you are calling the right path `/BackupRestore/BackupPolicies/$/Create?api-version=6.2-preview` instead of `/BackupRestore/BackupPolicies/MyBackupPolicyName/$/Update?api-version=6.2-preview`

Comment: I am using /BackupRestore/BackupPolicies/$/Create?api-version=6.4, but same error "FABRIC_E_BACKUP_POLICY_DOES_NOT_EXIST"

Comment: I tried Get all backup policy api and it is returning 200 , as i do not have any policy created result is empty

$url = "https://xxx:19080/BackupRestore/BackupPolicies?api-version=6.4"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType 'application/json' -CertificateThumbprint xyz

Response:
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {"Items":[],"ContinuationToken":null}
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Comment: Will be Better if you update the question with all the information, like the URL, the payload,  the cluster details

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you're sending but I've been successful in using [these](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.Dictionary/blob/master/ServiceFabric.Dictionary.DictionaryService/policies.http) calls to create backups.

```
### create new policy:
POST {{host}}/BackupRestore/BackupPolicies/$/Create?api-version=6.2-preview
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "MaxIncrementalBackups":  20,
    "Name":  "MainBackupPolicy",
    "Storage": {
        "ConnectionString":  "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=containerseverywherebckp;AccountKey===;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
        "ContainerName":  "backup-container",
        "StorageKind":  "AzureBlobStore"
    },
    "Schedule": {
        "Interval":  "PT15M",
        "ScheduleKind":  "FrequencyBased"
    }
}
```

Check the link for a complete scenario to configure backups for a service, including source code.

Comment: i am using api-version=6.4, but even when i tried using 6.2-preview i am getting different error as    Invoke-WebRequest : {"Error":{"Code":"E_INVALIDARG","Message":"Invalid API Version"}}

Comment: i am using the below body

$StorageInfo = @{
    ConnectionString = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xx;AccountKey=xyz;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net'
    ContainerName = 'backup-container'
    StorageKind = 'AzureBlobStore'
}

$runTimes = @("0001-01-01T09:00:00Z","0001-01-01T17:00:00Z")

$ScheduleInfo = @{
    Interval = 'PT15M'
    ScheduleKind = 'FrequencyBased'
}

$BackupPolicy = @{
    Name = 'DailyAzureBackupPolicy'
    MaxIncrementalBackups = 10
    Schedule = $ScheduleInfo
    Storage = $StorageInfo
}

$body = (ConvertTo-Json $BackupPolicy)

Comment: i am using the below command $url = "https://abc:19080/BackupRestore/BackupPolicies/$/Create?api-version=6.4"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Post -Body $body -ContentType 'application/json' -CertificateThumbprint yyy